# Scheduling jobScheduler jobs via adb in rooted device

Tags: android, adb, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler

I'm using the jobScheduler API for scheduling repeated job.
For testing, while running command `adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.foo.bar.application 1`. It is working fine in non rooted device but when i execute it in a **ROOTED DEVICE**, i'm getting the following exception--

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 0 not permitted to force scheduled jobs
```

The **run-as** reports it's not debuggable app.

How to test on rooted device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to unroot the adb shell.

The normal uid is 2000

```
uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)
```

You can switch the adb to non rooted mode with

```
adb unroot
```

Then try to run your command